# Specifying a generic type in java from Class object

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Why this is wrong:

```
    Class<? extends Number> type = Integer.class;
    ArrayList<type> = new ArrayList<>();
```

?

Is there no way to instantiate a class of a specific type given a class object?

---

Obviously I would never do that directly, that is just an example to show what is needed. In the actual code I need I don't know the name of the type. For example

```
    public void createAList(Class<? extends Number> type)  
{
    ArrayList<type> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<T extends Number> ArrayList<T> createAList(Class<T> type)  
{
    ArrayList<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    return toReturn;
}


ArrayList<Integer> intList = createAList(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Whoa, that did the trick!
THe only thing I am not clear is why it works. Do you have any links that explain this in great excruciating detail?

Comment: @CarrKnight This answer subtly shows that such a method is totally pointless. Notice that `type` isn't even used in its body.

Comment: yes, but again, this is a simplifying example for stack-overflow. I use the type arguments to create a couple of instances and return them in a "list".

Comment: @CarrKnight Then that's a much different question from what you've posted. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15281751/697449) to the question in its current form.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you use generics.  You don't use a `Class` object, you use the class name directly in your code.

```
ArrayList<Integer> = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am interested in the case where I don't know the name of the class. But I do have that information within the object Class

Comment: Your edited question makes it clearer what you want.  If you have the `Class` object, then use @irreputable's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Feel the difference between java [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (which actually generic too) object and class name.

You should use class name specifying generic type.

```
ArrayList<Number> = new ArrayList<>();
// ArrayList<Number.class> = new ArrayList<>(); <- WRONG
```

### UPD:

Use this approach if you'll know type only in runtime:

```
public <T extends Number> void createAList(Class<T> type) {
    ArrayList<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList<>` has to have a specific type it holds . You can put objects of that type or any sub-type in it though.

So use

```
List<Number> = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

and you can put `Integers` in it

*Notice how I used the interface on the left and the class on the right of the equal sign. That's a best practice sort of thing.*

If you want a list that will just hold `Integer` (as per your example) the answer by @irreputable is your best bet. This answer will hold `Integer` but not just `Integer.`

Comment: Thank you! But I am interested in the case where I don't know the name of the class. But I do have that information within the object Class. See If my edit made it any clearer

Answer (score 1):

Taken literally, the other answers' suggestions of how to implement `createAList` are ignoring something important: due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), such a method is pointless.

Given you want a `List<? extends Number>`, you can just write this:

```
List<? extends Number> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you just wanted a `List<?>`, you could write:

```
List<?> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you were in the scope of a type parameter `T` and wanted a `List<T>`, you could write:

```
List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```

Notice that a `Class` object has nothing to do with these constructor calls, just like the methods in the other answers. That's because at runtime, the `ArrayList` instance doesn't know or care about whatever generic type its references had at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to pass in an argument:

```
public <T extends Number> ArrayList<T> createAList () {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Though you may need to explicitly specify the type parameter when calling:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = this.<Integer>createAList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<type> = new ArrayList<>();
```

this line is wrong. First, you missed identifier (variable name) here; Second, you mixed the concepts of "type" and "class". You can delcare

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But according to yours, `type = Integer.class`. Obviously, `Integer` is not equivalent to `Integer.class`. Similarly you can't have `Integer.class i = 1;` The former one is a "type", the second one is a "Class" object.

You can create a generic method:

```
public <T extends Number> List<T> createAList (Class<T> type) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```