# using generic class as a list

Tags: java, reflection

I want to declare  `List<clz>` in the following code snippet. But it says `clz` cannot be resolved to a type. Any idea why? I'm new to java reflections.

```
Method method = user.getClass().getMethod(outerGetter);
Class<?> clz = method.getReturnType();
List<Class<?>> outerValues = (List<Class<?>>)ReflectionUtils.get(user, outerGetter);
```

Basically, I want outerValues to be a list of Java Type same as the method's return type. How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Kind of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280414/specifying-a-generic-type-in-java-from-class-object

Comment: There's no such thing as a `List<clz>`.  You can have a raw `List`, or a `List<Object>`, or a `List<?>`, and you could create all of them with `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman outerValues is a list of Java Type same as the method's return type. How can I achieve that then?

Comment: You can't do that type safely.  You'll have to do unsafe raw casts somewhere.